# Send large amount of data in Oracle in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, bulkinsert

[BEGINNER]
Sorry for my English.
I've been working for a new company for a short time and I consider myself a novice in BDD, since apart from school I haven't practiced since.

[ENVIRONMENT]
I am developing in C# an existing software that I need to optimize. With a big constraint, it is not to modify the bases since many customers already use them and will not want to change their server. In general if he uses ORACLE it is because he also uses it for other software.

The software used System.Data.OracleClient, but the latter is obsolete, I started implementing Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client. I can communicate, read and write data with the database, but I can't send a large amount of data quickly.

On site we have a server with a remote base which is therefore with Oracle, or MySQL (what interests me for the moment is Oracle)
And there are local workstations that use an SQLite database and must be able to operate without the remote database.

By default everything is saved locally and I have synchronizations to do if the remote database is accessible. It is therefore possible to have a large amount of data to transfer. (there are measurement records)

[FOR MY TESTS]
I recovered one of the customer databases in order to do tests with real data and one of the tables with more than 650,000 rows.
Transferring this line by line takes a lot of time, even if I don't make disconnection connections on each line of course.
I wanted to try to send parameter blocks, but I can't do it at the moment.

[MY RESEARCH]
I keep looking, but what I found was either using paid DLLs or I didn't understand their use.

[MY CODE]
For the moment I left on it, really in test:

````
        public void testOracle()
        {
            try
            {
                if (Connection == null)
                {
                    Connection = OracleConnection();
                }
                string commandString = "INSERT INTO GRAPHE (ID, MESUREE_ID, DATE_MESURE, POINT_GRAPHE, D0, D1) VALUES (:IDp, :MESUREE_IDp, to_timestamp( :DATE_MESUREp ,'DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'), :POINT_GRAPHEp, :D0p, :D1p)";
                int _ID = 1;
                int _MESUREE_ID = 9624;
                string _DATE_MESURE = "16/12/ 08 00:00:00,000000000";
                int _POINT_GRAPHE = 1229421394;
                int[] _D0 = 0;
                int[] _D1 = 0;

                using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(commandString, Connection))
                {

                    using (var transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < _ID.Length; i++)
                        {
                            command.Parameters.Add("IDp", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = _ID;
                            command.Parameters.Add("MESUREE_IDp", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = _MESUREE_ID];
                            command.Parameters.Add("DATE_MESUREp", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = _DATE_MESURE[i];
                            command.Parameters.Add("POINT_GRAPHEp", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = _POINT_GRAPHE[i];
                            command.Parameters.Add("DOS10p", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = _D0[i];
                            command.Parameters.Add("DOS07p", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = _D1[i];
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            Connection.Close();
        }


        public OracleConnection OracleConnection()
        {
            string serveur_name = "192.168.0.1";
            string database_name = "oracle.dev";
            string user_name = "name";
            string password = "pass";
            string oraclePort = "1521";
            OracleConnection _con = null;
            try
            {
                string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + serveur_name + ")(PORT=" + oraclePort + ")) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" + database_name + "))); User Id=" + user_name + ";Password=" + password + ";";
                _con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
                try
                {
                    _con.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
      
            }
            return _con;
        }
    }```
````

Comment: If I understood your question correctly that you want to insert multiple records into the database table?

Comment: Yes this is it.

I tried to put arrays in the Parameters value, but it doesn't want any.

I tried to do a for loop for adding one by one, until the ExecuteNonQuery(); but on the 2nd round he tells me that the object does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then you can create a DataTable and do bulk insert

```
using (var bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(yourConnectionString, OracleBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
{
   bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "GRAPHE";
   bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
}
```

You can also use the `BatchSize` property as per your requirement.

Comment: It's perfect, I got there.
I did a test to simulate a reality:
1) Reading SQLite with 330,000 rows, retrieving a DataTable.
2) Then recreate a Datatable from the one to recover, because I have one of the fields which is in Unixtime in my SQLite database, but in DateTime in Oracle.
3) Then I just applied your code and it inserted the 330,000 rows in 2-3 seconds, that's perfect, thank you very much.

It works with SQlite (in different ways), I thought it was not possible that there is no solution with Oracle, a paid software.

Thank you very much,.